# How to uninstall Rooms App?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, samsung-gear-vr

I checked my phone after class and I noticed that a new app was installed. I keep automatic updates off at all times so I have no idea how this application came to be on my phone. It is called rooms and has the android logo as its thumbnail. I have uninstalled the application numerous times and it just automatically installs again each time. I have tried researching the application and I've come up with nothing. When I click on the app, it tells me to insert my device into my Gear VR. So my question has two parts: First, is this a legitimate application that others have heard of? And second, is there a way I can remove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this advice on another chatroom:

Disabling "Facebook app installer" and "Facebook app manager" in app manager made this unwanted garbage stop harassing my precious S7.

it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root you can uninstall this apps by type in the terminal *pm list packages* and use grep to filter so like that *pm list packages | grep -i facebook* you can uninstall it by typing *pm uninstall [package name]*